# Trim string in column with substring in other column

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  "string": ["abc", "def", "ghi"],
  "substring": ["bc", "e", "ghi"]
})
```

Is an operation like this possible?

```
df['string']=df['string'].replace(df['substring'], r'')
```

expected result:

```
string substring 
a      bc        
df     e        
       ghi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lsit comprehension:

```
df['string']= [a.replace(b, '') for a, b in zip(df['string'], df['substring'])]
print (df)
  string substring
0      a        bc
1     df         e
2              ghi
```